# Bootstrap reordering works fine with 3.0, not with 3.1.1

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have three divs to be displayed in different order depending on screen width:

For lg it should be
3 7 2

For md it should be 
7 2 3

For sm it should be

2 3 7

I have this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-md-push-9 col-lg-push-0 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-2">
            <div class="well">
                <h1>3</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-md-pull-3 col-lg-pull-0 col-sm-7 col-sm-push-2 col-lg-push-0 col-md-push-0">
            <div class="well">
                <h1>7</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-md-pull-3 col-lg-pull-0 col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-10">
            <div class="well">
                <h1>2</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works as expected with Bootstrap 3.0, but Bootstrap 3.1.1 has following issue:

It works fine for lg and sm, but for md, 7 overlapse with 2 and 3...
[image: Columns overlapped]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
}
```

You can test the sample on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vowegini/2).

Comment: Yeah, it works...is this known issue in bootstrap, or it's a 'feature'?

Comment: @SlavenTomac Glad it works. If I recall correctly there were some changes applied in 3.1.1 to push and pull, but i may be wrong.

Comment: @SlavenTomac please add a reference to your post if you find the commit/answer or open an issue on https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues?state=open if you suspect this might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I reported issue on bootstrap as suggested by @MatijaGrcic...

It seems it was an issue in 3.1.1, but it's fixed in 3.2.

Link to reported issue : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13517#issuecomment-42241223

Here is fiddle that fixes it:

http://jsfiddle.net/VJqR7/2/

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.2.0-pre (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
```